# Kernel vs impulse response: what's the difference?

Tags: convolution, impulse-response, terminology

I am reading [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
Digital Signal Processing](https://www.dspguide.com/) by S.W. Smith. In [Chapter 9: Applications of the DFT](https://www.dspguide.com/ch9/3.htm) in the 3rd paragraph he writes "kernel (impulse response)"

What does it mean? What is meant by kernel? Is it same as impulse response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kernel is a more general concept, but an impulse response is a special case of a kernel. One usage of the term *kernel* is to describe an integral transform:

$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)K(\tau,t)d\tau\tag{1}$$

The function $K(\tau,t)$ is called the *kernel* of the integral transform.

If you compare $(1)$ to the convolution

$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau\tag{2}$$

then you see that the kernel of the convolution $(2)$ is given by

$$K(\tau,t)=h(t-\tau)\tag{3}$$

Note that the term *kernel* is also used to describe linear transformations in the discrete domain:

$$y[n]=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}x[m]K[m,n]\tag{4}$$

Discrete-time convolution is again a special case of $(4)$ with $K[m,n]=h[n-m]$.

In signal processing we regularly use linear transforms such as $(1)$ and $(4)$. The most well-known examples apart from convolution are the Fourier transform, the Laplace transform, the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform, and the Hilbert transform (which is in fact just a convolution).

Comment: What do you mean here "  The most well-known examples apart from convolution are the Fourier transform, the Laplace transform, the Z-transform, and the Hilbert transform (which is in fact just a convolution) "  ??  those all mentioned examples also use kernel??

Comment: @engr: Yes, they are all examples of linear transforms that can be written in the forms (1) or (4) with a specific kernel.